# Python- is it possible to create intermediate code use?

Tags: python

Can someone confirm if my below requirement is possible?
Basically, I want to create 2 applications,
First application should read a .csv data file consists of number and text store the values as an object or array and create an intermediate file.
My second application should read those intermediate files to use those objects for creating tables out of it like.

Note, both applications should be GUI based.

Is it possible to create such applications in python? As long as I understand I could use python bytecode package and create intermediate files, can anyone confirm this?

regards,

Comment: Yes, it's possible. That's not a suitable question for stackoverflow, however.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Sorry I didn't know where to ask thats why asked here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

YEs,you can create it.If you know how to generate intermediate file then it is possible.Make your application using tkinter module.From first application you can ask .csv file from user using .askopenfilename() and generate intermediate file.In second application use htmlwidgets(available in tkinter) to display data in table.